# MySQL Conditional For Which Join to use

Tags: mysql, join

On a query, is it possible to conditionally choose which join to use? On the query below, `m.bodyNo` is sometimes empty with the join bringing up the data using `m.chassisNo` instead and I would like it to show results for whichever one has the values.

```
SELECT m.`seriesYear`, m.`bodyNo`, m.`modelDesc` 
FROM parts_parsed p
    LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m ON p.`modelNo` = m.`bodyNo` 
    WHERE p.`partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

Trying two joins brings up all the data in my query tester (HeidiSQL) and it gives the same name for the relative columns of the two joins but would require providing aliases for each value and doing lots of conditionals in the PHP so I am looking for something more direct. Maybe something like COALESCE would do it but not sure how to apply it. Can anyone advise on how to proceed?

```
SELECT m1.`seriesYear`, m1.`bodyNo`, m1.`modelDesc`, m2.`seriesYear`, m2.`bodyNo`, m2.`modelDesc`  
    FROM parts_parsed p
    LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m1 ON p.`modelNo` = m1.`chassisNo` 
    LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m2 ON p.`bodyNo` = m2.`bodyNo` 
    WHERE p.`partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

If this doesn't lose its formatting, it is a sample of parse_parts:

```
ID  pageNo  baseGroup   partID  partNo  modelNo bodyNo  isRHD
1       1       0         1     391906  2201              0
2       1       0         1     391906  2202              0
3       1       0         1     391906  2211              0
4       1       0         1     391906  2220              0
5       1       0         1     391906  2222              0
43493   315     30      9983    386405            2250    0
43494   315     30      9983    386405            2251    0
43495   315     30      9983    386405            2270    0
43496   315     30      9983    386405            2271    0
43497   315     30      9984    438463            2650    0
```

This is a sample of parts_modelno

```
ID  seriesYear  bodyNo  chassisNo   engineNo    modelDesc
1   1948-49     2213        2213    G600000    HEARSE AND AMBULANCE
2   1948-49     2250        2226    G600000    7 PASS, CUSTOM EIGHT LIMOUSINE
3   1948-49     2251        2226    G600000    7 PASS, CUSTOM EIGHT SEDAN
4   1948-49     2252        2206    G600000    6 PASS, CUSTOM EIGHT SEDAN
5   1948-49     2255        2206    G600000    6 PASS, CUSTOM EIGHT CLUB SEDAN
6   1948-49     2259        2233    G600000    6 PASS, CUSTOM EIGHT CONVERTIBLE VICTORIA
7   1948-49     2262        2211    G200000    6 PASS, DELUXE EIGHT TOURING SEDAN
8   1948-49     2265        2211    G200000    6 PASS, DELUXE EIGHT CLUB SEDAN
9   1948-49     2270        2222    G400000    7 PASS, DELUXE SUPER EIGHT LIMOUSINE
10  1948-49     2271        2222    G400000    7 PASS, DELUXE SUPER EIGHT SEDAN
```

parts_modelno has fully populated values in all rows for both bodyNo and chassisNo columns while parts_parts has either bodyNo or modelNo with a few exceptions having both but in those few cases, the two values are the same. parts_modelno.chassisNo matches parts_parsed.modelNo.

Comment: I've just noticed that `p.id = 3` joins on to ***both*** `m.id =  7` and `m.id = 8`, and that both rows in `m` have identical `modelDesc`.  Is that intended?  *(Are the two rows in `m` actually different, or should there be some kind of de-duplication happening - owing to the identical descriptions?)*

Comment: Yes, the same chassisNo (chassis number) often had several different bodyNo (body numbers) although I'm not sure why the descriptions is the same on that one. Good observation but not of real concern as the data itself is still being tweaked. Sometimes these additions to the programming do help make things like that come to the surface, though, so I'll look into it.

Comment: @MatBailie I corrected the data in my question so no longer a duplicate. That was a good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely other, better, answers but this works.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(m1.`seriesYear`, m2.`seriesYear`) AS seriesYear, 
        COALESCE(m1.`modelDesc`, m2.`modelDesc`) AS modelDesc, 
        COALESCE(m1.`bodyNo`, m2.`chassisNo`) AS bodyNo 
    FROM parts_parsed p
      LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m1 ON p.`modelNo` = m1.`chassisNo` 
      LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m2 ON p.`bodyNo` = m2.`bodyNo` 
   WHERE p.`partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case method like this..

```
SELECT m1.`seriesYear`,
           m1.`bodyNo`,
           m1.`modelDesc`,
           m2.`seriesYear`,
           m2.`bodyNo`,
           m2.`modelDesc`
        CASE
            WHEN m2.value <> "" THEN m2.value
            ELSE m1.value
        END AS someName
    FROM parts_parsed p
    LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m1 ON p.`modelNo` = m1.`chassisNo`
    LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m2 ON p.`modelNo` = m2.`bodyNo`
    WHERE p.`partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

Comment: This seems promising although so far it gives an error but I am out with very limited Internet so will test better later when I'm back at the PC. One thing I did change was `<> ""` to `IS NOT NULL` as the fields with no value are `NULL` rather than empty.

Answer (score 0):

In various comments you state that you don't really care about performance, in which case you just want the simplest and most maintainable code?

So, just use an `OR` in the join predicate?

```
SELECT
  p.`baseGroup`,
  m.`seriesYear`,
  m.`modelDesc`,
  m.`bodyNo`,
  m.`chassisNo` AS modelNo 
FROM
  parts_parsed   p
LEFT JOIN
  parts_modelno  m
    ON p.`bodyNo`  = m.`bodyNo` 
    OR p.`modelNo` = m.`chassisNo` 
WHERE
  p.`partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

This assumes that `p` will never have both `bodyNo` ***and*** `modelNo` populated.  If that's possible, you'll need to update the question with an example of the behaviour you desire.

As mentioned elsewhere, this code also means that indexes can ***not*** be used to optimise the query plan.

***EDIT:***

If performance does matter *(and it should, even if you onoly mean cpu and disk utilisation rather than user experience)*, you should simply `UNION` two queries.  This allows the optimiser to fully utilise indexes to avoid pointless reads, chose better join implementations, etc.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p.`baseGroup`,
    p.`partNo`,
    m.`seriesYear`,
    m.`modelDesc`,
    m.`bodyNo`,
    m.`chassisNo` AS modelNo 
  FROM
    parts_parsed   p
  INNER JOIN
    parts_modelno  m
      ON p.`bodyNo`  = m.`bodyNo` 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    p.`baseGroup`,
    p.`partNo`,
    m.`seriesYear`,
    m.`modelDesc`,
    m.`bodyNo`,
    m.`chassisNo` AS modelNo 
  FROM
    parts_parsed   p
  INNER JOIN
    parts_modelno  m
      ON p.`modelNo` = m.`chassisNo` 
)
  part_list
WHERE
  `partNo` = '$PartNos'
```

The `UNION ALL` is preferred to `UNION` as that avoids `UNION`'s deduplication overhead.

The net result is that only one or other sub-query will contain any results for any given part, and that each sub-query can use different indexes for optimised resource utilisation.

- At the cost of longer code

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use `coalesce` for the join?

```
LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m ON p.modelNo = coalesce(m.bodyNo, m.chassisNo)
```

Comment: Note that this type of expression cannot be optimized with an index. The join must do a table-scan of `m` for each row of `p`.

Comment: Yes that's a valid point. No idea how large the OP's data set is, for tables with only hundreds of rows and/or low concurrency it might not be a concerm.

Comment: It's pulling up a limited number of records based on $PartsNos value but the table itself has over 300,000 rows of data although speed is really not an issue for this low-traffic hobbyist old car site. I am pretty sure that COALESCE is part of the solution but am too rusty (like the cars) to figure it out. I tried `LEFT JOIN parts_modelno m ON p.`modelNo` = COALESCE(m.`bodyNo`, m.`chassisNo`)` but there were no results.

Comment: Maybe add a small sample of data to your question that demonstrates the issue? Like @BillKarwin points out the join condition is effectively an `or` criteria which will likely require a scan (I'm not sure if MySql can utilise index intersections), but you can at least choose a trade off between easier to write code or better performance.

Comment: I added samples of the data. Actually, I don't really care about performance too much as the difference in however it's done will not be noticeable to the end user.

Comment: It's the `p` table that has two columns containing one value, not the `m` table.  Then, the `m` table has both columns populated, but shich one to join on depends on which column in `p` is populated.  Therefor, logically speaking, this should be `ON p.modelNo = m.ChassisNo OR p.bodyNo = m.BodyNo`, though that will still prevent index use.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I believe I corrected that before I saw your comment. Yes, the m table has both columns populated. You explained it far more succinctly than I was able!